# Bounding $P(|X-\mu|\geq \alpha)$ using $E[|X|]$

Tags: probability

Given $ X $ is a random variable with $E[X] = \mu < \infty$, show that for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} $ $$ P(|X-\mu|\geq \alpha) \leq \frac{2E[|X|]}{\alpha} $$ I tried using Chebyshev's inequality, but I don't know that $\text{Var}(X)$ exists, and even if it does exist, it only gives me $$ P(|X-\mu|\geq\alpha) \leq \frac{\text{Var}(X)}{\alpha^{2}}=\frac{E[X^2]-\mu^2}{\alpha^{2}} $$Which doesn't seem to help me very much.

Comment: First of all, you have not assumed that $EX^2<\infty$ and hence applying Chebyshev's inequality is not a good idea. Also the inequality demands a decay like $1/\alpha$ this suggests that you need to apply Markov's inequality. And the inequality you need is a direct consequence of Markov inequality.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho I tried applying Markov's inequality with $|X-\mu|$, then I got $E[|X-\mu|]$, and I need in order to show the wanted inequality, I need to show that $E[|X-\mu|] \leq 2\mu$, which I can't see how to prove.

Comment: Do you have $E[X]=\mu$ or $E|X|=\mu$? If you have the latter then triangle inequality does you job as $E[|X-\mu|]\le E|X|+\mu=2\mu.$ While if you only assume $EX=\mu,$ then the conclusion is false.

Comment: In your title, you write $\mathbb{E}(|X|)$, but in the text of your question it is $\mathbb{E}(X)$.  Is this a typo?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

$$
E\big(|X-\mu|\big)\le E\big(|X|+|\mu|\big)
$$
by the triangle inequality.

(Note that you need to specify $\ \alpha>0\ $ for the inequality to be true, not merely $\ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}\ $, as you currently have)